# How can I create a static fftw library for a Matlab Mex file?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, fftw

I have a mex function that I'm compiling using the MinGW version of the mex command where I'd like to use fourier transforms. I'd like to use a static version of the fftw library on windows, however, I'm struggling to find resources explaining how I can generate this library without figuring out entirely new tools. I'm using Matlab 2020b and/or Matlab 2021b. I've found several stack overflow posts discussing how to compile using cmake, VScode, Visual Studio, etc, but I'd like to avoid having to go down those rabbit holes (if possible!).

Also, I can only find a copy of the .dll file in Matlab's program files directory. I know Matlab uses fftw for their fft implementation, does it not have a static library that I could link to?

Comment: Why do you want to link to a static library? It’ll be easy to have you MEX-file depend on the DLL that comes with MATLAB!

Comment: I thought I'd like the mex file to stand on its own so if I move it around and use it in a different folder it would still work. However it's occured to me that by definition, if I'm using a mex file, Matlab must be installed, and therefore the root directory dll must be there regardless of the computer, so I think that might make more sense

Comment: As a follow up question, how can I use the dll in my Mex function? I've tried adding a mex option -L.... and including fftw3.h but I'm getting a compile time error saying it can't find fftw3.h.

Comment: Well, you do need to have the header file (just download it and put it next to your other source files for your MEX-file). It’s only needed at compile time.